# mPDF not genereting pdf on live server

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have met this issue, I have been working with mPDF very fine. But I had to switch my hosting server and it is no longer generating pdf but displays just the content without an error here is my code to generate the pdf. any help?

```
<?php  include("../../mpdf60/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('P','A4');   
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');  
// LOAD a stylesheet    
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../../mpdf60/mpdfstyletables.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text  
$report_content=ob_get_contents();  
$mpdf-> WriteHTML($report_content,2);
$mpdf-> Output('Students_Reports.pdf','I');?>
```

I have tried to display all errors and I fixed them but still it is not generating the pdf :(!

Comment: Having almost the same issue. Did find any solution?

Comment: I had to contact my hosting service people for help, it was on their side not my codes.

Comment: One more thing, Do you have any idea about what they did? Because my provider is not getting me right.

Comment: perhaps this may help, https://kb.infopark.de/8d4b8b24895a8916/den-pdf-generator-aktivieren?locale=en I have lost all the discussion we had but what I'm sure they made some tune ups on their Apache server. it's a tool I don't recall the name they added

Comment: Thank you but still in the sea...